# List Items are not rendering in Child Component ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to list the array on the child component modal from parent
Like, whenever a user click on particular row, modal will pop up and display the user details

When i pass the props to child and print the console.log, it display fine in console.log but list is not rendering in Modal

Here is my Code

```
export default function TransitionsModal({ open, setOpen, editItem }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  console.log("Children Items", editItem); //this line prints details of particular user
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <h2 id="transition-modal-title">User Details</h2>
            <p id="transition-modal-description">

              //THIS PART IS NOT RENDERING

              {editItem &&
                editItem.length &&
                editItem.map(items => {
                  return <p key={items.id}>{items.name}</p>;
                })}
            </p>
          </div>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Output Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gJz5.jpg)

Comment: You don't need to add condition rendering for map

Comment: tried without condition. same problem

Comment: @LogeshP, The data which you receive from ```editItem``` is an object as per the output image you provided.. You can use ```editItem.map``` only if it is an array.. So in this case you can directly use  ```{ return <p>{editItem.name}</p>``` ..

Comment: i want to display all the items not only name.. do i need to add separatly for each one ?

Comment: @LogeshP, In question you mentioned only name so I have given name here.. If you want to give each property separately as it is an object.. First check whether it works for ```editItem.name``` and let me know if this works..

Comment: that works fine

Comment: @LogeshP, If that is your requirement then I will post it as an answer.. Shall I proceed?

Comment: yep. I was about to say that to post it as the answer so that i can upvote and accept the answer

Comment: @LogeshP, Posted it as an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your output, the data you receive is an object not an array.. So this block of code,

```
{editItem &&
   editItem.length &&
   editItem.map(items => {
   return <p key={items.id}>{items.name}</p>;
})}
```

Won't work.. It works only the data you receive is an array.

So already you receive the right data in `editItem`, So you can directly return the user details such as name like,

```
{ return (<p>{editItem.name}</p>) }
```